# storing data for a html/javascript application

Tags: javascript, html, browser

My little sister's learning english and french. I want to make a small browser vocabulary for her so that she could add (delete) new words to the list and browse through the words she has already learnt. But I don't know what is the preferred way to store data in this case. Maybe, JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

It allows you to cache string-data in your browser. Watch out for `Incognito Mode` as the `localStorage` get's cleared when the window closes.

Otherwise, if you want your code to work on all browsers then you'd have to use a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tampermonkey and localStorage to make an app to record words. however 
I guess that the chrome browser extension can reach you requires.such as [magoosh-vocabulary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magoosh-vocabulary/oooelhhaglnggehlocjjmgngfknfclak)、[words discoverer expandy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/words-discoverer-expand-y/noncaeikjgpbdeoocblijjgegnobogib)